# How can I create an "add a repo" RPM?

Tags: fedora, rhel, yum, repository

Some things like [Fedora's Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux (EPEL),](https://www.fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) provide a package to install a repository

> EPEL has an `epel-release` package that includes **gpg keys** for package signing and repository information. Installing this package for your Enterprise Linux version should allow you to use normal tools such as yum to install packages and their dependencies.

If I want to create my own repository, is there a tutorial/docs on creating my own package to install that repository?

Answer (score 2):

The `epel-release` package is just a [src.rpm](https://ewr.edge.kernel.org/fedora-buffet/epel/8/Everything/SRPMS/Packages/e/epel-release-8-8.el8.src.rpm) you can build using `rpmbuild` and put the resulting RPM in a yum repo. The spec file just contains a key and the repo file that get installed in the `%install` part of the rpm build process.

If you're familiar with how to build an RPM, the below links should help you out with the basic template of how the `epel-release` RPM is built:

- [EL7 spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/epel-release/blob/epel7/f/epel-release.spec) and [files](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/epel-release/tree/epel7)
- [EL8 spec](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/epel-release/blob/epel8/f/epel-release.spec) and [files](https://src.fedoraproject.org/rpms/epel-release/tree/epel8)

Comment: the `epel-release` package exists as a normal rpm, it is not necessary a src.rpm.
Your answer is partly correct though, you could just say it would suffice to package the repo and key file.

Comment: @ChrisMaes I don’t know why you’d argue that there isn’t an epel-release Source rpm when it is trivial to find it on an EPEL mirror.  For example: https://sjc.edge.kernel.org/fedora-buffet/epel/7/SRPMS/Packages/e/epel-release-7-12.src.rpm

Comment: @jsbillings. I don't say that the SRPM doesn't exist. I'm saying that that information is secondary to this question and doesn't really help.